# How to change font color for hyperlinks

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I'm rather new to the LaTex system. Can anyone help me with instructions on how to change the font color to blue for a hyperlink? thanks! 
I've added `\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue}` to the preamble
how should I now define the hyper references in the other files?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "in the other files". E.g., do you have a main or "driver" file as well as other files that are loaded from the driver file and contain the body of the document? Please advise.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that sets up the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This will also serve as a test case and ensure that the solution actually works for you and go a long way towards eliminating any confusion in how you are actually applying the `\hypersetup`.

Comment: I am confused by your comment about "other files" but I think that you just want `\hypersetup{colorlinks = true,linkcolor =blue}`. See the [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) manual for more options such as `citecolor`

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the color of hyperlinks you first need to load the `hyperref` package. Then, the set up of colors is possible with the following command `\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,linktocpage=true}`